# Q: Yii2 load data from database

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, yii2, uikit

I have problems with loading data from database. 
My goal is to implement a MVC which dynamically shows in the view the values stored in the db table. So, in the Project model I have this code:

```
     public function search($params)
{
    $query = project::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'position' => $this->position,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'is_deleted' => $this->is_deleted,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'description', $this->description])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'link', $this->link])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'image', $this->image]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

In the Controller:

```
     public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SeachProject();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

And in the view (index.php):

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
            'title',
      'description',
      'image',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Well, it works but I need to print the values into Uikit cards and not through Gridview limitations (which is actually the only way I know). I should have one card for each record in the table with an image (the url in the image field of the table) and a link (the url in the link field of the table).
Any words of advise would be good, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ListView](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview) and create any kind of structure using UiKit cards or material design.

> The ListView widget is used to display data from a data provider. Each
>   data model is rendered using the specified view file. Since it
>   provides features such as pagination, sorting and filtering out of the
>   box, it is handy both to display information to end user and to create
>   data managing UI.

A typical usage is as follows:

```
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;


echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_ui-card',
    'viewParams' => [
       'fullView' => true,
       'context' => 'main-page',
    ],
]);
```

The `_ui-card` view file could contain the following basic card html :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;
?>
<div class="uk-card">
    <div class="uk-card-header">
        <h3 class="uk-card-title"><?= Html::encode ( $model->title ) ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-body"><img src="<?= Html::encode ( $model->image ) ?>"><?= Html::encode ( $model->link ) ?></div>
    <div class="uk-card-footer"></div>
</div>
```

This way you can show every project as a separate card using the view file.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, it is the very thing I wanted! Now can someone tell me if there is the possibility not to show the writing 'Showing 1-13 of 13 items' and 'Home/Project' above?

Comment: @gipsy you can use the `$layout` option to customize them see here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview#$layout-detail